# How to change activity with left-right swipe

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, swipe

How to change activity with left-right swipe?

I did not find the manual anywhere.

*Example:*

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your first link, its called `ViewPager`.

Follow one of the awesome [tutorial](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/) it will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). See [this](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) part of the documentation for details on sliding screens with it.