# Can't resolve R aapt.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1 and many other such errors

Tags: android

I am getting a cannot resolve symbol issue. Sometimes on `R` and sometimes on `ViewPager`.

I am trying to use fragments for swiping screens and I have followed a solution from [How to change activity with left-right swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965124/how-to-change-activity-with-left-right-swipe).

I do not know what is wrong with Android Studio or with my project. It is giving errors whenever I build it.

[image: errors]

[exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XV0E.png)

Comment: Please post your log in textual format rather than as an image.

Comment: Could not determine Java version using executable C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\java.exe.
this is all what, log says, in fact it is not building gradle when i restarted :/

Comment: did you fix this error??

Comment: Please post excat screenshot of your error so we can help you

Comment: @Jeeva i did ask this question first but i got no response then i did another, error posted

Comment: @danishali please provide correct details,so we can help you out.you seem to provide incorrect data so how can we help you??

Comment: @Jeeva i humbly mentioned that my INSHORT app was not working then, so I provided another app's data, from which I got the same error. but this, 'exact error' is of same app

Comment: ok bro sorry i could get it

Comment: did u fix it???

Comment: if not post your build .gradle files both app and project level

Answer (score 0):

First, check your xml files and xml references(findById 's etc.)

Then, **Clean Project** and afterwards **Make Project** and **Rebuild Project** should make it.

Comment: this , clean project is done  100 times but it doesn't "Make Project" it gives error